# Как узнать id пользователя телеграм

Tags: telegram, telebot

Как узнать id пользователя телеграм зная его имя (@name) (билиотека telebot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам простой бот, будет присылать id, если ввести команду start

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message,message.from_user.id)
```

message.from_user.id - вот, что вам нужно

чтоб узнать свой id, можно использовать готовых ботов @my_id_bot